# android:alignment of text in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app in which i have to use edit text and when i use this text on samsung galaxy s and emulator , the text starts from center of edittext rather than starting from top.The screen shot and code is as follows`

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/tester" 
     android:layout_height="113dip" 
     android:layout_width="420dip" 
     android:background="@drawable/textarea_reason" 
     android:paddingTop="-90dip"/>
```

[image: When i enter the text in edit text it starts from some gap rather than starting from top]`

Comment: remove that padding top  and try

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change gravity parameter.

Java Code

```
editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP| Gravity.LEFT);
```

XML

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/tester" 
    android:layout_height="113dip" 
    android:layout_width="420dip" 
    android:background="@drawable/textarea_reason" 
    android:gravity="top|left"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Update yor Edit Text tag like as...

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/tester" 
    android:layout_height="113dip" 
    android:layout_width="420dip" 
    android:background="@drawable/textarea_reason" 
    android:gravity="top|left"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set Back ground image thats why this problem occurs put 
android:paddingLeft="20dp" and test

Answer (score 0):

Try setting edit text's properties `singleLine="false"` in the xml or `minLines` to > 1